# SQL Select Is referencing composite PK/FK table required?

Tags: sql, select, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables with their primary keys:

```
PLANT      DEPT      HOLDER
------     ------    ------
pId        dId       hId
```

Following are their relationships:

```
1.) A department exist in many plants.
```

For which I designed the table having composite key PK/FK as

```
DEPTinPLANT
-----------
{p_Id,d_Id}
```

and another relationship,

```
2.) A holder can be assigned to many departments of a plant.
```

with composite PK/FK from DEPTinPLANT and HOLDER tables

```
HOLDERinDEPT
------------
{{p_Id,d_Id},h_ID}
```

Now extracting data from HOLDERinDEPT with Select statement, I have

```
select *
from HOLDERinDEPT 
join PLANT  on p_Id = pid
join DEPT   on d_Id = dId
join HOLDER on h_id = hId
```

Is this correct or is it required to reference first the DEPTinPLANT table then then corresponding base tables?

Comment: Have you tried to create the tables, add insert some sample data and execute your query?

Comment: yes everything ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from HOLDERinDEPT hd
join PLANT p on p_Id = pid
join DEPT d  on d_Id = dId
join HOLDER h on h_id = hId
```

This is correct.
No need to reference DEPTinPLANT

Comment: Noted. Because im worried skipping reference will cost me some inconsistencies later on.